Get Android app label name from package name, using only Python
I can get all the package names of android apps on a phone. But I don't know how to get the app label of each of them.
I tried to find information in dumpsys, but did not find any.

To retrieve the Android app's label name (application name) using its package name, you can utilize the aapt tool (part of Android SDK) and subprocess in Python. The process involves extracting the app's APK from the device and then reading its manifest for the label.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
